# Size of conduit for two 4 gauge THHN and one 10 gauge ground wire

Tags: conduit

what size of FMC conduit I can use if I have two conductors that are 4 gauge THHN and one 10 gauge wire?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

That configuration is not a legal one unless the #4 is aluminum wire and the ground is copper.

If your feeder/circuit is >60A then you need a #8Cu or #6Al ground.   If it is <=60A then you are using wire larger than is required, perhaps for voltage drop reasons. Regardless you need to bump the ground wire in proportion as well.

#4 copper + #8 ground would be acceptable.
Also #2 aluminum and #6 aluminum ground would be a better bargain.
Both will fit in 1” FMC.

Be warned that FMC is difficult to pull because the flex in it will fight you.

If this is for an EV, let's talk. There are many, many, many misconceptions about EV charging.  We see lots of unnecessarily costly overkill installations, and even more panel fires looking for a place to hpapen because people ignored the NEC Article 220 Load Calculation. Useful EV charging can be done safely and cheaply at any home, and I don't mean level 1.

Comment: Hi, yes, you guessed it right!  I've been researching to install an EV charger and my head is spinning as there are so many options available.  How do I contact you?  Email would be great.  Thanks!!!

Comment: No need to email Harper. He has written his thoughts *many* times here, and I 100% agree with him on this. Basically, unless you are going to use an EV for 150+ miles per day, or *multiple* EVs 100+ miles per day each, a 20A or 30A 240V circuit is plenty. Don't worry about occasional long trips - half the time you'll be elsewhere when your battery is low, plus that's what Superchargers are for. Figure out what 90% of your daily travel will be, then backtrack to figure out how many miles per hour of charging you will need. Odds are 30A will be more than enough.

Comment: @GreenEarth2129 Yeah, you can get 100-150 miles in a 10-hour night on a simple 20A circuit run with cheap #12 UF. People who need *a lot* more than that probably don't pick EVs.  Back when my family ran a business and ran all over a large metro, our panel limitations would have limited us to 3 units Power Sharing 30A total, *and that would have worked*.  EVen EVangelists like Technology Connections, AgingWheels and Out of Spec Reviews on Youtube - they *have* 50A circuits in their garage, but their daily charging is 30A because they just don't need more. Anyway, ask more questions!

Comment: I 100% agree with you'll that charging need depends on daily usage and unless driving 200+ everyday, we do not need the full 48amp (~45 miles/hr) vs 40amp (~30 miles/hour) charging station. My estimation (for a 25' run), price difference is about $100 whether I use the direct wired wall connector or install a NEMA 14-50 receptacle (assuming industrial grade receptacle). So, cost-wise, it is not significant. Some other advantages I can think of (wall connector) are: it is direct wired/less termination points, integrated GFCI, plus some more, I think. Hope my reasoning is not too absurd. Thanks!

Comment: @GreenEarth2129 Feel free to ask new questions.  Your starting point is a NEC Article 220 Load Calculation on their house's service, to figure out how many amps the house's service can safely support.  Once you know that, you have a maximum for circuit size.  With the Wall Connector I would hardwire - the socket adds cost and failure points, although the socket allows aluminum wire to the socket.  If using the travel unit EVSE, Tesla makes 8 different dongles for that, 6 of them cover 240V every amp range from 15A to 50A.  You must use a factory dongle; a homebrew adapter will overload!

Comment: Dear @Harper-ReinstateMonica, thank you so much for your suggestions and taking time to respond. I looked at some other conversations on this forum where you and others provided excellent suggestions.  You are correct: I am figuring out how many amps my breaker panel (220v) can support. I have daily usage over a year. I asked the utility company to give me either 15 min or 1 hr data, more appropriate to determine max load (15 min or hourly) over a year. I will let you and others know if Iany more questions. This forum has been very helpful - I and many others appreciate your help.  Thanks!!!

Comment: @GreenEarth2129 Code requires that you use NEC Article 220 to determine your Load Calculation, not some freestyle method. In residential the periodic **averages** are useful for sizing batteries, but useless for safety, since all large loads except for EV charging are transient and are shorter than the measurement interval.  Something like this. https://www.cityofsacramento.org/-/media/Corporate/Files/CDD/Building/Forms/CDD-0213_Electrical-Load-Calculation-Worksheet.pdf?la=en

Comment: Hi, thanks for the example. I will definitely put numbers that are appropriate for house. Although I may need some help. The formula I am using is: (existing max demand*1.25) + (full load of the new device) has to be less than 200amps. Looking at my hourly or 15-min data over last one year and finding the maximum would give me the existing max demand.

Comment: @GreeaneEarth In my last message I was trying to explain that you cannot use power company usage data as a substitute for a Load Calculation. It's not for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The [Southwire calculator](https://www.southwire.com/calculator-conduit) gives the answers, but always heed Harper's warnings about everything else.

- 2 Copper THHN 4 AWG + 1 Copper THHN 10 AWG - 3/4" FMC
- 2 Aluminum THHN 4 AWG + 1 Copper THHN 10 AWG - 3/4" FMC
- 2 Copper THHN 4 AWG + 1 Copper THHN 8 AWG - 3/4" FMC
- 2 Aluminum THHN 2 AWG + 1 Aluminum THHN 6 AWG - 1" FMC

Comment: Except 3/4" barely fits and is going to be murder to pull.  FMC tends to fight you.

Comment: Thanks, I could use a 1" conduit - the price difference is not that great for the length I need.

Comment: Definitely a good idea. That way you have a little more wiggle room (literally) and you can run the conduit even while still working out which wires you are going to use.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your vote of confidence.  What I am finding is that 'everything' is regulated by 'code', which is great.  I am hoping going to 1" conduit is probably not against the code/best practice.  I found a site where it calculates which conduit size is best if I use two 4 gauge copper THHN and an insulated copper ground (10 gauge) and it gave me 3/4" is okay.  But as many of you suggested, 1" is better (and as I said, not bit price difference for the run I need). Thanks!

Comment: There may be exceptions somewhere, but generally speaking conduit size is a *minimum* and larger is always OK. In fact, many people, many times, will use larger than the minimum because: easier to pull, allow future upgrades to larger wire (e.g., small wire now for one circuit, replace later with larger wire to a subpanel), allow multiple circuits (there are limits on that beyond simple conduit fill, so 3 or maybe 4 circuits per conduit max.), or simply stock fewer sizes (similar to Harper only using 12 AWG and not any 14 AWG wire).

Comment: Great points - I did not think of the possibility of future updates!  Thanks again, I feel much better :).  Wishing you the best.